# I am trying to import VertexAIModelGarden from langchain, but getting an ImportError

Tags: python, langchain, google-cloud-vertex-ai, large-language-model

I am trying the VertextAIModelGarden from langchain.llms from an example from below link,

https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/google_vertex_ai_palm

here is the code snippet,

```
from langchain.llms import VertexAIModelGarden
```

whenever I am trying to execute the above line it gives me below error,

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'VertexAIModelGarden' from 'langchain.llms'
```

Can anyone here help me in executing above line in notebook with env having below versions

1. python --> 3.8
2. langchain --> 0.0.345
3. google-cloud-aiplatform --> 1.35.0

Comment: According to this page, it seems like it should be `from langchain.llms.vertexai import VertexAIModelGarden` https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/llms/langchain.llms.vertexai.VertexAIModelGarden.html?highlight=vertexaimodelgarden#

Comment: Hi @Him Singhvi,did the above comment solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in my notebook, could you see if your version is right in the notebook not terminal?

[image]